# Handle XMLHttpRequest data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

How do I handle XMLHttpRequest data? I have a javascript/angular controller that takes some images and sends it to another page where I want to store the images to a database.

My code lokes like this:

```
modal.controller('UploadController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.files = new Array();

    $scope.getFiles = function (element){
        $scope.$apply(function($scope){
            for (var i = 0; i < element.files.length; i++) {
                $scope.files.push(element.files[i])
            }
            console.log('files lenght : ' + $scope.files.length);
        });
    };

    $scope.uploadFile = function () {
        var data = new FormData();
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        for(var i in $scope.files){
            data.append("uploadedFile", $scope.files[i])
        }

        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false)
        xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false)
        xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false)
        xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false)
        xhr.open("POST", "fileupload.html")
        $scope.progressVisible = true

        xhr.send(data);
    }

    function uploadProgress(evt) {
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                $scope.progress = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
            } else {
                $scope.progress = 'unable to compute';
            }
        })
    }

    function uploadComplete(evt) {
        alert(evt.target.responseText);
    }

    function uploadFailed(evt) {
        alert("There was an error attempting to upload the file.");
    };

    function uploadCanceled(evt) {
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.progressVisible = false;
        })
        alert("The upload has been canceled by the user or the browser dropped the connection.");
    };
});
```

In the the response text from the alert I get to see the html code from fileupload.html.
How can I recieve the data in fileupload.html so I can store the images in a database?

Comment: This is how XMLHttpRequest works right? or do i get the idea totally wrong ?

Comment: When building an Angular application; it is best to think in terms of "screens" and not pages. I don't understand what sending an image from one page to another means in this context. That said; usually I wouldn't use xhr directly; you'd use one of the $http methods which [I'm pretty sure] use xhr under the hood.  That said, your code looks right. When making a remote service call, If you want different data back from your service, you'll have to change that service to return different data.  Does your fileUpload.html not save your image to a database in any way?  What is the code behind that?

Comment: there is no code in fileUpload.html except for <html></html> :)
basicly my question is what do i put here. (thanks for the tip over $http ill look into that)

Comment: @cancho What you put there depends on your server side language.  If you using ColdFusion; you'll need to use a cffile tag. I expect any server side language will have a similar 'feature' that allows you to handle an uploaded file.

Comment: So i can handle the XMLHttpRequest just like a uploaded file ?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: on the fileUpload.html i can handle the incoming XMLHttpRequest just like as if a file was being uploaded to that page ?

Comment: I believe the answer is yes; but I'm really not understanding the question.  I must have a blind spot.